# How to load a library file /dll at start up of jboss. I am using fedora

Tags: dll, jboss, webserver, startup, fedora

I want a dll/library file e.g (abc.so) to load while start up of jboss, loading dll/library file after login is not a problem. I am using fedora.
Do I need to write something in JBoss's bootstrap run.bat OR place that dll/lib file in some directory ? Or what ?

Comment: Wait, you want to load a Windows DLL during the boot of JBoss on Fedora? Or am I missing something?

Comment: In fedora it will be .so file.

Comment: What would be the purpose of it? I mean, if the .so is already on the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, it should be easy to invoke it from Java using JNI, no matter which app server (if any) is in use.

Comment: Thanks jpkrohling, It is requirement of application that a certain library file to be loaded at Jboss's start-up. You mean only I need is to add that lib path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH ? and It will handle rest of the matter.